# How can I use the Google Maps API to find landmarks near a given location?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to be able to use the Google Maps API to give me a list of the nearest landmarks from a given location. Consider a situation where I give latitude and longitude to the Maps API and in return it gives a list of landmarks (collection of latitude and longitude coordinates). Is this possible with the Maps API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends what you mean by landmark, but the [Google Place Search API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) sounds similar to what you're asking for. In each request, you need to pass in a location, the maximum distance from the location you want results from and optionally the type of place(s) you want to search for. The list of supported place types is [here.](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types)

If you go through that list and decide which ones you class as landmarks, then you could search for just those by separating the types with a pipe symbol in your search string. e.g. (type1|type2|etc)

Comment: To add on this, do you know how to find the nearlest landmarks from a given location based on the landmark definition by: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/recognize-landmarks ?